# QByteArray from QFile

Tags: c++, c, qt, opengl

I want to read a byte array into a 3D texture.

```
QFile file(filename);
if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{

    return false;
}
QByteArray* data = new QByteArray(file.readAll(),  m_ImageWidth*m_ImageHeight*m_ImageCount );

glGenTextures(1, m_textures);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, m_textures[0]);
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, m_ImageWidth, m_ImageHeight, m_ImageCount, 
             0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

Can I do this? I get access violations in my project and I want to check if they could come from here.

It is a write violation at `glTexImage3D()`

Comment: Note that there is no reason to create the QByteArray on the heap.

Comment: For all further viewers, the error was caused by not properly initializing the `m_textures` array.

Comment: Btw, `QByteArray` implements COW, so you don't need to allocate instance of array with new. Just create it on stack.

Comment: I haven't heard of that, thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `data` variable holds a pointer to a place in memory where the QByteArray object is stored, but the actual data it encapsulates are stored somewhere else. When `glTexImage3D` tries to read big block of memory starting at the `data` pointer, it runs into unmapped memory.

To get pointer to the acutal data, use data->constData() instead. [QByteArray::constData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#constData)

Comment: unfortunately, the error persists: Exception at 0x0, code: 0xc0000005: write access violation at: 0x8, flags=0x0 (first chance)

Comment: Thx for the hint though, makes perfect sense, so I got my answer!

Comment: For any further readers, the error came from using Qt5 with glew. The build in Qt OpenGL is actually OpenGL ES, which doesn't support GLTexture3D. You have to use Qt 4.8 to use glew along with it.